# How to integrate SMS Gateway with the server of parse.com

Tags: php, android, ios, parse-platform, sms-gateway

I need to verify phone number of my app users in the same way as truecaller, whatsApp does.

I contacted many SMS Gateway providers. Their API are supported to php, java, ASP.net(C#), VB.net, ASP. They have SMS scripts that supports the above platforms.

The problem is that I am using the free server of parse.com in which we the mobile developers do not need to care about server side script. Parse.com does not provide sms gateway. But SMS gateway is needed according to my requirement.

Is it possible to integrate SMS gateway API with parse ?

or should I just migrate to php server..?

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: what ? you do it all in app.  Your java checks the phone number against parse.com if true then send sms via sms api if false then fail.  Its pretty simple/basic logic work flow.

Comment: First user will enter his phone number, It will sent to parse.com ! Then the work comes of sms gateway to send a unique number sms to that phone number message inbox, then the user can see it & type the same in my app. If the user writes the same code number then it is verified. Dave, Thanks 4 ur comment, I didn't understand even 1% of your above comment. Please elaborate it more

Comment: basically its your workflow.  You don't need to integrate parse.com AND an sms gate way you just have to hook them both into your app.  Since you already know how to use the parse.com api and you get your true or false back in the true section just integrate an SMS gateway providers api there and you're away.

Comment: The sms gateway providers are giving me php script, If I have a php server then I can use the php script. The problem is I do not have any php server

Comment: ignore the php script just look at its api and then build for the api. the php script will just run some curl requests probably to send the message. you can replicate this functionality in your app code using probably the same code you use for contacting parse.com

Comment: Thanks I truly understand your point now,BTW This is the java code http://www.smsgatewayhub.com/bulk-sms-gateway-api/java-sms-script that can be used in android.

Comment: well there you go put the try inside an if(parse.com==true) and you're good to go

Answer (score 1):

Check out digits which is a new thing from twitter.

"Digits lets people create an account or sign into your app using nothing but their phone number on iOS and Android. Built using the same global, reliable infrastructure Twitter uses, Digits will verify the user’s phone number with a simple customizable user interface that easily integrates into your app.
Digits extends your existing user/profile database. A successful Digits account creation will return a stable userID to attach or match with your user record, and an oAuth token for the device. A verified phone number is also returned for convenience, but the user’s number may change at any time and should not be used for authentication.

We plan to extend Digits to include web login support, as well as the ability for users to find their friends via their address books."

Source: https://blog.twitter.com/2014/introducing-fabric